# Changing text in a paragraph using vba word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to change text in a paragraph using vba word. The following code causes the Next to not go to the next element in the collection.

```
 Sub ReadPara()
 Dim myString$
 Dim DocPara As Paragraph

 For Each DocPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
   'Debug.Print DocPara.Range.ParagraphStyle '; " - "; DocPara.Range.Text
   If Left(DocPara.Range.ParagraphStyle, Len("Heading")) = "Heading" Then
     Debug.Print DocPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString
   End If
  'This section does not go to the next element in the collection
  If InStr(DocPara.Range.Text, "HW") > 1 Then
    Debug.Print DocPar; qa.Range.Text
    myString$ = DocPara.Range.Text
    DocPara.Range.Text = myString$ & "Changed"
   '  Debug.Print DocPara.Range.Text
  End If
 Next DocPara
 End Sub
```

Comment: Does it throw any kind of error or exception?

Comment: If you don't have `Option Explicit` declared at the top (which you ideally should) your code execution should not stop assuming you have declared `qa` somewhwere. If para contains "HW" then it will get changed by the statement `DocPara.Range.Text = myString$ & "Changed"` Can I see your word doc? BTW What is `qa`? If you do not handle the code properly there is a chance that it can get into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Second problem:

`ParagraphStyle` is read-only, use `Style` instead. Both are of type `Variant`, so you don't use `Set`.

Try this:

```
DocPara.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
```

Comment: @engineerMike OK, great. You close the question by accepting the answer and with a vote up, if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I have overcome my first problem and no it wasn't the typo. The typo was just in the message and not in my code. Now I just can't seem to change the style of the newly modified paragraph.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub ReadPara()
     Dim myString$
     Dim myHeading$
     Dim DocPara As Paragraph

     For Each DocPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
       If Left(DocPara.Range.ParagraphStyle, Len("Heading")) = "Heading" Then
         myHeading$ = DocPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString
       ElseIf InStr(DocPara.Range.Text, "HW") > 1 Then
         myString$ = DocPara.Range.Text
         myString$ = Replace(myString, "HW", "HW-" & myHeading$)
         DocPara.Range.Text = myString$
         'The line below doesn't work at all
         Set DocPara.Range.ParagraphStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
       End If
     Next DocPara
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Now the code works except I still don't go to the next paragraph. I seem to stay on the same paragraph. The next DocPara isn't working like I would expect.

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub ReadPara()

    Dim myString$
    Dim myHeading$
    Dim DocPara As Paragraph
    For Each DocPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
       If Left(DocPara.Range.ParagraphStyle, Len("Heading")) = "Heading" Then
          myHeading$ = DocPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString
       ElseIf InStr(DocPara.Range.Text, "HW") > 1 Then
          myString$ = DocPara.Range.Text
          With DocPara.Range
             myString$ = Replace(myString, "HW", "HW-" & myHeading$)
             .Text = myString$
             .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
          End With
       End If
    Next DocPara
    End Sub
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, look at the paragraphs.count value to see if it is changed. In my case, when I change the range.text value, the count gets reset to 1 and the for loop stays on the first paragraph.

Comment: if it can be of use to somebody: the error I mentioned in the previous comment was due to the fact that I was trying to modify selection.paragraphs. The solution was to modify my code to modify selection.range.paragraphs instead.

Answer (score 1):

The following line will cause an error and (depending on your error handling) probably causes execution to break out of the loop:

```
Debug.Print DocPar; qa.Range.Text
```

If you enter `Option Explicit` in the top of each code module (in order to force every variable to be explicitly declared), this kind of error will probably be found earlier. :)

Comment: If `Option Explicit` is not mentioned then the user will not get any error and that debug.print line will not stop the code execution. In case option explicit is mentioned already then user will get a message but this doesn't seem like it. I believe the error is somewhere else.

Comment: The debug-line I mentioned is probably a typo , but it will result in an error. If there is no `Option Explicit` but an `On Error Resume Next` statement in the procedure calling the `ReadPara` sub, execution will skip out of `ReadPara` without completing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
 For Each DocPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
   'Rest of your code it here
 Next DocPara
```

Use

```
 For p = 1 to ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
   'Rest of your code it here
    'use the script below when refering the the specific paragraph
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(p). 
 Next p
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be Next p rather than Next DocPara?